# Fill an Unsigned Char Array

Tags: c++

I would like to fill an unsigned char array with the value `0xFC` using C++. I have tried the following, but it did not seem to work.

```
unsigned char buffer[8] = {0xFC};
```

This seems to place everything in the first array index in the buffer. Below is the Eclipse IDE output when I inspect the value of the buffer:

```
buffer[0] = 252 '\374'
buffer[1] = 0 '\000'
buffer[2] = 0 '\000'
buffer[3] = 0 '\000'
buffer[4] = 0 '\000'
buffer[5] = 0 '\000'
buffer[6] = 0 '\000'
buffer[7] = 0 '\000'
```

I would expect the following:

```
buffer[0] = 1 '\001'
buffer[1] = 1 '\001'
buffer[2] = 1 '\001'
buffer[3] = 1 '\001'
buffer[4] = 1 '\001'
buffer[5] = 1 '\001'
buffer[6] = 0 '\000'
buffer[7] = 0 '\000'
```

or the reverse because of my platforms endianness.

Anything else that I have tried just gives me the ASCII representation of the numbers. There is something fundamental that I am not understanding here...

Comment: You'd expect it to split the value into its constituent bits, and then put one bit in each byte?

Comment: You might use std::fill

Comment: That expectation is completely insane. Where did that come from?! You have an array of *chars*!

Comment: I don't understand: 0xFC == 252 == {octal} 374.  There is no endianness issues with single byte values.

Comment: Is your issue with the quantity of numbers or the representation?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes, I originally thought that each index would be a bit - I was obviously not understanding the datatype. I see now that each index is a byte.

Comment: @KerrekSB I now see the insanity. Sorry for asking a dumb question.

Comment: See my answer below about `std::bitset`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You are right, I misunderstood the endianness issue. I thought it would affect my value but now I see that endianness would only come into play with multiple byte values.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews My issue was with the representation. The value 252 was not being represented like I thought. I wasn't understanding the datatype. I see now that a char is a byte - dumb question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to create an array whose elements contain individual *bits* of a number. You can try this:

```
unsigned char value = 0xFC;

unsigned char bits[CHAR_BIT];    // "bool bits[CHAR_BIT]" would be better

for (size_t i = 0; i != CHAR_BIT; ++i)
{
    bits[i] = value % 2;
    value /= 2;
}
```

Here's a slightly nicer variant without an explicit loop:

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>

template <std::size_t ...I>
constexpr std::array<bool, sizeof...(I)> get_bits(std::index_sequence<I...>,
                                                  unsigned char value)
{
  return { static_cast<bool>((value >> I) % 2)... };
}
```

Usage:

```
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::cout << "You said: " << n << ", which has bits: ";
    for (bool bit : get_bits(std::make_index_sequence<CHAR_BIT>(), n))
        std::cout << bit;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: There's probably some `std::index_sequence` kind of variadic constexpr solution, but I don't quite see it yet.

Comment: Well, `std::bitset` exists.

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. This makes more sense - way more than the craziness I had before...

Comment: @Rapptz: Ah, very interesting. Please do post an answer around that! I think we have way too few good code snippets showcasing `std::bitset`.

Answer (score 0):

An `unsigned char` in most systems is 8 bits, affectionately known as a byte.

An array of 8, unsigned char (bytes) is 64 bits total.

You are telling the compiler to assign the first slot in the array to 0xFC, which it did.

Maybe you are thinking of `std::bitset` which is an array of bits.

What do you want as the end result?

Comment: I wanted the end result to be 252 in a byte - which it did. I was incorrectly thinking that each array index would be a bit.